# pl/sql : extract after concatenated?

Tags: plsql, clob, wm-concat

```
select wm_concat(COLUMN_NAME) A FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS where table_name like 'T_EMPLOYEE';
```

How to extract the data out from `A` and assign it to another `varchar2` variable?

Comment: Since wmsys.wm_concat will give you a comma separated list, i am assuming you need to separate out the values in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to store it in a VARCHAR2 variable for further processing, you can do it with something like:

```
DECLARE
  BUFF_V VARCHAR2(2000); -- make sure there's enough space or add some substr
BEGIN
  SELECT wm_concat(COLUMN_NAME) 
    INTO BUFF_V 
    FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS 
   WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'T_EMPLOYEE'; 
END;
```

If you don't want to bother with the parsing of the wm_concat, you can just use something like:

```
DECLARE
  COL_V VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
  FOR QUERY_C IN (select COLUMN_NAME FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS where table_name like 'T_EMPLOYEE') LOOP
    COL_V := QUERY_C.COLUMN_NAME;
    -- do whatever you want with COL_V
  END LOOP;
END;
```

This will iterate on all results (all column names of table T_EMPLOYEE) storing them in the COL_V variable.

Answer (score 0):

I know there is an accepted answer already but just FYI, **wm_concat** will not work if your version is upgraded on 12c.

You may use **LISTAGG** as an alternative so why bother use an undocumented feature.[Read this](https://blogs.oracle.com/oracle-database-app-admin/entry/why_not_use_wm_concat)

Just saying.

Cheers =)